# ansible lookup in file with ; delimited based on 2 variable

Tags: csv, ansible, yaml, lookup

- Ansible lookup in file with semi colon; delimited & lookup based on 2
  variable

  #Input csv file:

  ```
  Sysport;name;address;column1;port;column2;column3
  host001$port0;host001;x.x.x.10;x.x.x.10:port0,x.x.x.11:port0;port0;port0;envq1
  host001$port1;host001;x.x.x.10;x.x.x.10:port1,x.x.x.11:port1;port1;port1;envq1
  host001$port2;host001;x.x.x.10;x.x.x.10:port2,x.x.x.11:port2;port2;port2;envq1
  host001$port3;host001;x.x.x.10;x.x.x.10:port3,x.x.x.11:port3;port3;port3;envq1
  host001$port4;host001;x.x.x.10;x.x.x.10:port4,x.x.x.11:port4;port4;port4;envq1
  host001$port5;host001;x.x.x.10;x.x.x.10:port5,x.x.x.11:port5;port5;port5;envq1
  ```

  code

  ```
  ---
  - name: lookup example  
  # Include host, group of hosts
    hosts: [dummy]
  # Count of servers to run in batch
    serial: 10
  # Collect basic information from servers
    gather_facts: True
    #ignore_unreachable: true
  # Execution tasks



   tasks:

  - shell: ls /directory 
    register: port   

  - debug: 
      msg: "{{ lookup('csvfile', inventory_hostname ~ '$' ~ item file=/ansible/files/repos.csv delimiter=; col=3 }}"
    with_items:
      "{{ port.stdout_lines }}"
  ```

  Error:

  ```
  TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
  fatal: [dummy1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! template error while templating string: expected token ',', got
  ```

  'file'"}

  expected: result

  value of 'server_repo' in message

Comment: As said on your other question: a general rule from [Ansible's FAQ](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names): *Another rule is ‘moustaches don’t stack’.*

Comment: So, you should at least try: `msg: "{{ lookup('csvfile', inventory_hostname ~ '$' ~ item file=/ansible/files/vips.csv delimiter=; col=3 }}"`

Comment: And a general note on question on StackOverlfow: including your expected output is nice and you should keep on doing it, but you should also include error message and/or the actual output of what you have so far. See [ask]

Comment: I'll include the error message for sure, I'm editing my question.

Comment: msg: "{{ lookup('csvfile', inventory_hostname ~ '$' ~ item file=/ansible/files/vips.csv delimiter=; col=3 }}" using this I'm getting an error, updating the qustion,

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/csvfile.html#examples), the `csvfile` lookup wants the 2nd argument as a string, not a freeform collection of tokens (to say nothing of the missing closing paren in your example):

```yaml
- debug: 
    msg: "{{ lookup('csvfile', inventory_hostname ~ '$' ~ item ~ ' file=/ansible/files/vips.csv delimiter=; col=3') }}"
  with_items:
    "{{ port.stdout_lines }}"
```

at your discretion, you can also extract that csv key part to a `var` since the `vars:` blocks are evaluated for every iteration:

```yaml
- debug: 
    msg: "{{ lookup('csvfile',  my_csv_key ~ ' file=/ansible/files/vips.csv delimiter=; col=3') }}"
  vars:
    my_csv_key: "{{ inventory_hostname ~ '$' ~ item }}"
  with_items:
    "{{ port.stdout_lines }}"
```

both work the same, but the 2nd may be a little easier for folks to mentally parse

Comment: ~ is approximate match ? if yes how do I use exact match like in excel vlookup match condition True & False

Comment: `TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
fatal: [dummy1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! csvfile: list index out of range"}` this time I got a different error.

Comment: Is there a limit for csv file lookup in ansible?

Comment: no, [the `~` is string concat](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#other-operators) -- you are probably safe to use `+` if its easier to reason about; and for the list index error, edit your question with the verbose error, but my _guess_ is that your file doesn't always have 3 columns. I don't know the limitations for csv file lookup